# Command line tool to remove passwords in cred manager

Tags: windows, batch-file

I found a post on superuser to delete all creds from windows credential manager.
https://superuser.com/questions/689456/what-is-the-windows-7-command-line-to-remove-all-remember-passwords-in-credentia

```
Code:
echo on

cmdkey.exe /list > "%TEMP%\List.txt"
findstr.exe Target "%TEMP%\List.txt" > "%TEMP%\tokensonly.txt"
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%G IN (%TEMP%\tokensonly.txt) DO cmdkey.exe /delete:%%H
del "%TEMP%\List.txt" /s /f /q
del "%TEMP%\tokensonly.txt" /s /f /q

pause
```

This works on windows 7 but does not work on windows 10 and i'm not able to figure out why. cmdkey.exe /list still functions in windows 10 and it still pipes the file so i assuming the issue is with findstr.exe for an issue with the for loop in the batch file but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: What message does the `cmdkey` command outputs when you manually try remove a single credential from the credential manager on Windows 10? Also, I've made an improvement to your script since it's not necessary to temporary store the credentials in files: `for /f "tokens=2" %%g in ('cmdkey /list^|findstr Target') do cmdkey /delete:"%%g"`

Comment: Thanks for the improvement. It seems the issue is only occuring on my local PC. later last night i spun up a VM and it worked there and on other peoples machines. Permissions also seem to be an issue. I can't have it stored in a network location not owned by the person running it, which seems to be the primary fault of this. i feel like i have to create a script to run my script to launch a script to delete my script. -_-